# Multiple MutableLiveData change results in a single MutableLiveData

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata, mediatorlivedata

In my android project, I have three MutableLiveData variables. Upon the change of their values, I want to change the value of another MutableLiveData and observe its value to make an API call. Is the process I followed a standard approach? Or are there any other good approaches?

**ViewModel Code**

```
    private MutableLiveData<ChemistEntity> chemist = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<List<OrderPreviewRequest.LineItem>> lineItemList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<String> paymentType = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isAllDataReadyForCall = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void checkAllDataReady() {
        ChemistEntity chemist = this.chemist.getValue();
        List<OrderPreviewRequest.LineItem> productListValue = this.lineItemList.getValue();
        String paymentTypeValue = this.getPaymentType().getValue();
        boolean allReady = chemist != null && productListValue != null && paymentTypeValue != null;
        isAllDataReadyForCall.postValue(allReady);
    }
```

**Fragment Code**

```
private void subscribeUiToChemist(LiveData<ChemistEntity> liveData) {
        liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), chemist -> {
            mViewModel.checkAllDataReady();
        });
    }

    private void subscribeUiToPaymentType(LiveData<String> liveData) {
        liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), paymentType -> {
            mViewModel.checkAllDataReady();
        });
    }

    private void subscribeUiToLineItemList(LiveData<List<OrderPreviewRequest.LineItem>> liveData) {
        liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), lineItems -> {
            mViewModel.checkAllDataReady();
        });
    }

    private void subscribeUiToIsAllDataReady(LiveData<Boolean> liveData) {
        liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), isReady -> {
            if(isReady) {
                mViewModel.callApi();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've used a MediatorLiveData, but you're using it as a MutableLiveData, not making use of any of its properties.
Now, you can change chemist to be a MediatorLiveData and add the other liveDatas as sources of the chemist MediatorLiveData.

```
private MediatorLiveData<Boolean> isAllDataReadyForCall = new MediatorLiveData<>();
```

in ViewModelInit:

```
isAllDataReadyForCall.addSource(chemist, {chemist -> checkAllDataReady()})
```

and the same for the other two liveDatas.
Then you can remove all the observers in Fragment, but the one of isAllDataReady.

Comment: I edited my code. Chemist is also a MutableLiveData. I tried your approach. But it have a problem. If one of the field value change, checkAllDataReady() method doesn't called. I want it should be triggered if chemist/lineItemLIst/paymentType will change.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue seems to be that LiveData only emmits when being observed. To fix this you can add a *fake observer* in the Fragment. This means observing it but not doing anything with it.
Also, you shoud be using setValue instead of postValue, i recommend you to check the docs on this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).